# How to fix "Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

(Discord ticket system )
Im getting the error

```
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
```

> SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context"

And I don't know how to fix it, Anyone can help?

```
if(command == "ticket-setup")
        // ticket-setup #channel

         let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();

        if(!channel) return message.reply("Usage: **ticket-setup <#channel>** ")

        channel.send(new.discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Support/ Help Ticket System')
        .setDescription('React to this message to create a ticket!')
        .setFooter('Gta V Rp assistant')
        .setColor('00ff00')
        );
        
        
        sent.react('e_mail');
        settings.set(`${message.guild.id}- Ticket`, sent.id);

        message.channel.send("Ticket system set up!")
}
);
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is missing the opening bracket: `{`. So just add that in: `if(command == "ticket-setup") {`

Comment: Additionally `new.discord.MessageEmbed` should be `new discord.MessageEmbed` or `new Discord.MessageEmbed`, depending on your import/require.

Comment: When I do that the opening bracket red lines even when I close it at the end...

Comment: In that case, there's probably some other error outside this code snippet. You can click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64294095/edit) button to add details to your question - please include more code before and after this snippet.

Comment: Sorry I totally mis understood and was putting the open bracket in the wrong place, Its worked now thanks so much appreciate it!